# APISubscriptionError 400 Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: api, real-time, instagram

I found a lot of posts about this issue, but none is like mine.

I have a website that subscribes to IG real-time updates. Since some time ago trying to subscribe to new notifications returns the above error. Seems like IG can't reach the callback_url.

Interesting findings while troubleshooting:

1. I tried to manually (directly) access the callback_url and it works flawlessly.
2. When I run the site on my local machine and make sure the callback_url is to my server + the verify_token is a valid one then it all works as it should! IG reaches the callback_url.
3. I used the apigee console to make the subscription request and there it sometimes works.. Meaning - I craft the request to IG API and click Send. If it fails then I click again (I don't change parameters) and then it works..
4. Web server logs are in line with the results I get (when it complains it can't reach then there's no log of a request).

Does anyone have any tip or suggestion how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While chasing my own tail for a solution I also contacted IG support. I described the issue using same description as above.

After 2 weeks suddenly everything started working again. Magic! Suddenly no errors at all! Needless to say nothing has changed on my end (hardware / network / code).

I didn't receive any response from their support, but considering that a previous email to them a few months ago took about 2 weeks to answer then I am quite sure some support guy simply fixed the issue on their side and didn't even bother to let me know what was going on.

This could be related to the fact that they killed most of their real time notifications API.

Anyway, leaving this here so that if anyone encounters a similar issue then just know you may need to email IG support.